# Matlab Arbitrary Output Argument Combination Disgarding

Tags: function, matlab, optional-arguments

Is it possible to check whether the Matlab function output argument `N` is disgarded by its caller (`~` given in call) or not provided one of its `N+K`, `K>1`, is defined, that is when `nargout > N`.

For instance, given

```
function [x,y] = f()
    ...;
end
```

we would like to detect that x does not need to be calculate by `f()` in the call

```
[~,y] = f();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible. See 
[this blog entry from the Matlab page](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/) in particular [this comment](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/#comment-30597).